# Sequence check on Partitions in Postegresql 10

Tags: postgresql, sequence

It is possible to mantain an unique sequence on a partitioned table?
I am using Postgresql 10

Comment: What is a "unique sequence"? If you mean a unique *constraint* backed by a `SERIAL` or `BIGSERIAL` (i.e. generated by a sequence)... then no, not yet.

Comment: You could create a single [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) and use that for every partition.

Comment: Yes Craig, excuse my lack of details , I meant unique constraint backed by a BIGSERIAL

Comment: Tks, Horse, as usual, you got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is with 9.6. I'm not sure why you would want to do that though - could you explain more about why you need ids to be unique across partitions?

```
CREATE SCHEMA so46793511;
set search_path=so46793511;
CREATE SEQUENCE partitioned_seq;
CREATE TABLE partitioned (
  id integer default nextval('partitioned_seq'),
  val text
);
CREATE TABLE partitioned_1 ( LIKE partitioned ) INHERITS (partitioned);
CREATE TABLE partitioned_2 ( LIKE partitioned ) INHERITS (partitioned);
INSERT INTO partitioned_1 (val) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c');
INSERT INTO partitioned_2 (val) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c');
SELECT * FROM partitioned;

DROP SCHEMA so46793511 CASCADE;
```

NB: this doesn't include anything fancy to [auto-pick partitions when inserting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

Comment: This is right, but as Horse with no name, suggested me, the solution for my question, create a single sequence and use that for every partition. similar anyway to yours